# Using JUJU bundles in the JUJU-GUI machine view

Tags: juju

I would like to use the openstack-base juju bundle in the juju-gui.

Ideally I would like to drag and drop the bundle from juju charms search results and then use the machine view to manually place the charms on specific machines. Once I'm happy with the arrangements of units, etc. I would like to commit and have juju deploy to the machines.

As it stands, as soon as I drag the bundle into the juju-gui, juju starts to auto-deploy to machines of its own choice. There is no intermediate step that allows me to review and then commit.

Is it possible to take a charm store bundle and manually arrange placement before commit and deploy?

Answer (score 2):

As of Juju GUI 1.4.0 you now get a change set generated when importing, or dropping a bundle. For more information you can see the blog post http://blog.jujugui.org/2015/06/17/juju-gui-1-4-0-un-committal-release/ and the overview video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sr631pNXXzQ

<s>The current release of the Juju GUI (1.3.5) does not support modifying bundles pre-deployment. We are working on adding this functionality right now to the GUI. You can expect that feature to be added in the next couple of weeks.</s> I'll be sure to update this post when it's released but also keep an eye on the blog http://blog.jujugui.org/ and the twitter account https://twitter.com/jujuui

In the interim you can copy the bundle file to your computer, modify its contents, then drag and drop it onto the GUI to deploy it.

Comment: Excellent! This feature will be very useful. Thanks for the reply and thanks for all your hard work on juju-gui.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I have updated the post because what you're looking for is now supported in the GUI!